# SDWebImage + MBProgressHUD (асинхронная загрузка с веб + вращающийся индикатор)

Tags: ios, xcode

Добрый день!

Использую указанные две библиотеки при загрузке полноразмерной картинки с web.

КОД:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^
{
    [imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", img]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stub_image.jpg"]];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    });
});
```

}

Получается что картинка загружается позже, чем скрывается индикатор.

Что не так делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) функция sd_setImageWithURL и так работает в фоновом потоке, ее не надо засовывать в dispatch.

2) Чтобы индикатор исчезал после загрузки изображения, то Вам необходимо использовать SDWebImageManager.

Т.е.

```
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
[manager downloadImageWithURL:imageURL
                      options:0
                     progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
                         // progression tracking code
                     }
                     completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
                         if (image) {
                              // тут нужно установить изображение на Ваш imageView и скрыть HUD
                             imageView.image = image; 
                            [self.HUD hide:YES];
                         }
                     }];
```